# Producing a new dataframe from an old dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to produce a `new` dataframe from an `old` big one (many variables)
I use the `cbind.data.frame` function and it goes like this

```
new <- cbind.data.frame(old$var1, old$var2, old$var3)
str(new)
  'data.frame': 100 obs. of  3 variables:
$ old$var1        : num
```

Why does the var1 still belong to `old$` ?
I wanted to use just `new$var1` but it returns `object not found`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just `new <- old[c("var1", "var2", "var3")]`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Combine both of the other other answers by doing this:

```
New <- data.frame("var1" = old$var1, 
                  "var2" = old$var2, 
                  "var3" = old$var3)
```

Comment: thank you all for your sugestions, I particuarly like this one because it gives you the opportunity to change the variable names

Answer (score 3):

You are doing nothing wrong, you just need to rename the columns in your new data frame using:

```
names(new) <- c("var1","var2","var3")
```

Now, you will be able to use `new$var1` , and so on.

Hope this solves your problem.